# Tomcat and domain pointing

Tags: java, tomcat, dns

I've set-up `tomcat` and my application is running at the following url

```
http://104.131.198.95:8080/Onlinetest/
```

> Here's what I'd like to do:

1. I have a domain **xpertus.in**
2. I'd like this application to display as soon as someone tries to load **xpertus.in**, in other words, I want the application to run as a website and not as an ip-address.

> Things that I already know are as follows:

1. I have setup **ns3.mumbaionweb.in** and **ns4.mumbaionweb.in** to point this ip address
2. I can now anytime point the domain to the above mentioned name servers.

> Things that I need help with:

1. How do I configure tomcat to display application as a domain website and not ip address.

I would really appreciate some help here.

Comment: If you want to expose it on port 80 (implied by _"display as soon as someone tries to load xpertus.in"_) then **run** it on port 80 to start with.  And BTW this question is off-topic here. It belongs on [sf].

Answer (score 0):

According to DNSGoodies, that domain is pointing to an entirely different address: 204.11.58.87.  You'll want to start out by getting the domain to point to the correct address.  Then configure your router to forward port 80 to 8080 on the machine running Tomcat.